# Set a check constraint for text array in Postgresql

Tags: arrays, regex, postgresql, constraints

I'm having a table called `student`, with `id` and `name` as fields in `PostgreSQL`:

```
Create table student (id int, name text[]);
```

I need to add the constraint for the `name` field. Which means it has to accept only character for that field. But the field name is a text array.

I tried this check constraint:

```
Alter table student 
add constraint stud_const check (ALL(name) NOT LIKE '%[^a-zA-Z]%');
```

But it throws this error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error atERROR:  syntax error at or near "all"
LINE 1: ... student add constraint stud_const check (all(name) ...
 or near "all"
```

How could I solve this problem? The `constraint` should be set to **whole array**.

Comment: What is the purpose of this array? Is a student supposed to have more than one name?

Comment: yes, I'll store first and last name in that

Answer (score 4):

It is necessary to [`unnest`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE) the array to match it to a [`regular expression`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP):

```
select bool_and (n ~ '^[a-zA-Z]*$')
from unnest(array['John','Mary']) a(n)
;
 bool_and 
----------
 t
```

[`bool_and`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-AGGREGATE-TABLE). Since it is not possible to use a subquery in the check constraint wrap it in a function:

```
create function check_text_array_regex (
    a text[], regex text
) returns boolean as $$

    select bool_and (n ~ regex)
    from unnest(a) s(n);

$$ language sql immutable;
```

and use the function in the check constraint:

```
create table student (
    id serial,
    name text[] check (check_text_array_regex (name, '^[a-zA-Z]*$'))
);
```

Test it:

```
insert into student (name) values (array['John', 'Mary']);
INSERT 0 1

insert into student (name) values (array['John', 'Mary2']);
ERROR:  new row for relation "student" violates check constraint "student_name_check"
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (2, {John,Mary2}).
```